# How to keep variable value use throughout all records in clistview

Tags: php, yii, clistview

i have used clistview.

my requirement is to print total on each record.

like following in randerPartial _view.php,

1'st record

```
total= total+$data->amount(value 100);
total=100;
```

2'nd record

```
total= total+$data->amount(value 100);
total=200;
```

3'rd record

```
total= total+$data->amount(value 100);
total=300;
```

and so on....

but i cant get last updated value of total variable.
it overwrite value in each record. how to keep variable updated and used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution will be to create a variable in your controller like

```
class AbcController extends Controller
{
    public $total=0;
}
```

and then use it in your renderPartial _view.php like

```
$this->total += $data->amount(value 100);
```